# Geometry problem need some help

Tags: geometry

At the midpoint of line segment $AB$ which is $p$ units long, a perpendicular $MR$ is erected with length $q$ units. An arc is described from $R$ with a radius equal to $\frac{1}{2}AB$, meeting $AB$ at $T$. Then $AT$ and $TB$ are the roots of:

$\textbf{(A)}\ x^2+px+q^2=0\\ \textbf{(B)}\ x^2-px+q^2=0\\ \textbf{(C)}\ x^2+px-q^2=0\\ \textbf{(D)}\ x^2-px-q^2=0\\ \textbf{(E)}\ x^2-px+q=0$

Comment: Please draw a figure.

Comment: @David G. Stork  this what I came for !!!

Comment: I have no idea where $R$ is (and thus $T$).

Comment: @David G. Stork    
   Problem 47 https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1954_AHSME_Problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an application of Pythagoras theorem. In particular, $$TM^2 = TR^2 -MR^2 = \frac{p^2}{4}-q^2 \implies TM = \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-q^2}.$$ Presuming $T$ lies between $A$ and $M$, we have $$AT = \frac{p}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-q^2},$$ and $$TB = \frac{p}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-q^2}.$$
Note that $AT+TB=AB=p,$ and $AT\cdot TB = q^2$.

Consequently, $$(x-AT)(x-TB)=x^2-(AT+TB)x+AT\cdot TB = x^2-px+q^2.$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $D$. Let $A$ be the origin, then $B$ will have coordinates $(p,0)$ and $R$ will have $(p/2,q)$. The equation of the ark will be $y=q-\sqrt{-x^2+xp}$. Now all we need to find is where $y$ will intersect axis $x$

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt.
$M$ is the midpoint of $AB$. Let us use $R$ as the origin of a coordinate system.
In this system a circumference centered at $R$ of radius $\frac{p}{2}$ is described as $$ x^2 + y^2 = (\frac{p}{2})^2 $$
The segment $AB$ lies on a line of equation $y = -q$, so the x-coordinate of the two intersection points ( $q$ is small enough) are given by $$ x = \pm  \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4} - q^2} $$ 
The distances $AT$ and $TB$ will then be given by
$$ \frac{p}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4} - q^2}$$
to be conveniently re-written as 
$$ \frac{p \pm \sqrt{p^2 - 4q^2}}{2} $$
which resembles of course the formula for the solution of a quadratic equation.
All is needed to close off is to check which one of the quadratic equations is solved by the latter expression: for starters, $p$ has to be preceded by a $-$ sign, $q$ by a $+$, and so on..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the figure.  I think that this is the hardest part of this problem.

There are two possible points for $T,$ but it ultimately does not matter which one you choose.

[image]

Use the Pythagorean theorem to find MT.

$MT = \sqrt {(\frac p2)^2 - q^2}$

and simplify:

$MT = \frac {\sqrt {p - 4q^2}}{2}$

$AT = \frac {p + \sqrt{p^2 - 4q^2}}2\\
TB = \frac {p - \sqrt{p^2 - 4q^2}}2$